# keycloak helm chart to use external database?

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy keycloak helm chart in Google Kubernetes Engine, I want to use external database like google cloud postgres.

thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bitnami helm-chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm) with an external Database

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install keycloak bitnami/keycloak
```

we need to add the following values to `values.yaml`

```
externalDatabase:
  host: external-cloud-host
  port: 5432
  user: USER
  database: DATABASE_NAME
  password: PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following chart : https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak

You will be able to connect your keycloak instance to a google database by using the `extraContainers` parameter.

The readme explains how to do that : [Using Google Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#using-google-cloud-sql-proxy)